# SQLite resets when Project is Re-ran in Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite

I downloaded the source code located here on how to do a simple "To Do List":

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/09/22/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-4/

What I notice is when I add anything to the list and then re-ran the simulator... whatever I added is not saved.

I installed the app on my phone and notice that the database is reseted when the Phone is turned off.  The app works fine... but when the Phone is turned off (hold power button for 5 seconds) and when it turns back on... whatever I added to the To Do list is gone.  It's like it's just writing to the database temporarily.

I spent several days on this and can't figure it out why it keeps getting deleted after phone is turned off.  Source Code is here:

http://staging.icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/todo-part-41.zip

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are calling the initializedatabase everytime you run the app. Then the app copies a new copy of the database so the default data is back. Try debugging, you should only run that method if the database isn't existing...

Comment: I tried to comment out initializedatabase from (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application... but the app just crash.